# different style of android event handing

Tags: android, oop, model-view-controller

I found that there are two style of code writing in event handling of android. One is calling method like setOnClickListener and pass an anonymous class in java, the other is adding a xml attribute named **onClick** and writing a corresponding method in the Activity, which is shown below.

```
<Button  
android:id="@+id/idButtonTest1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/button_test1"
android:onClick="myClickButton1"/>
```

I want to know which one is better in oop perspective(or in mvc perspective) and which one is more easy to change in the future?

Comment: both are same.there not much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same the only difference is for fragments.

If You set listener for view in xml, method has to be in activity hosting this element.

If Your fragment with onClick listener is going to be hosted in different activities and You set onClick in xml You will have to implement same method in all activities.
In that case it is better to implement onClickListener interface in fragment class and set listeners for click-able views in code in onCreateView() method.

Comment: OK,No big difference unless dealing with fragment.I got it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no backend difference in these two ways. if you use `android:onclick` attribute then java set the `onClickListener` for you.

But for maintainace I think `android:onClick` attribute is slightly better (personal opinion). For Example

1. you do not need to setTheOnclickLister from the code. So no need to inflate the view for this.
2. no effect on code if id of view is changed.

But the above advantagese are too minor.

Comment: OK,but after considering it seriously, I prefer writing onClickListener in java code as I want to divide my view and controller a bit.Any way, I got the idea.And there is no big difference.Thanks a lot

Comment: @henry yes definitely you have your own choice. as both are almost same so you better choose one in which you feel comfortable